# Not able to load attachment sent through flask-mail

Tags: flask-mail

I'm trying to send an attachment through flask-mail. The email is sent, the attachment is also present in the email but I cannot open the attached file.
Gmail shows a message **Couldn't Load Image** when i click on the image attachment.

This is my code :

```
    msg = Message('You have a new Message', sender = 'noreply@gmail.com', 
                                        recipients = ['user@gmail.com'])
    msg.body = f'''Details are - 
    Name : {form.name.data}
    Email : {form.email.data}
    Phone : {form.phone.data}
    Template : {form.template.data}
    Message : {form.message.data}
    '''
    msg.attach(
        form.details.data.filename,
        'application/octect-stream',
        form.details.data.read())
   mail.send(msg)
```

Where am I wrong ?